What underlying distribution does one use while calculating the Stutzer Information Statistic?
Cramer's Theorem is used to derive this form for the Stutzer Information Statistic $I_p$:  $$
I_p=\max_\theta -\log(E[\text{e}^{\theta r_t}])
$$
Here, $r_t$ is the portfolio's excess returns over some time window. However, this requires the underlying probability of each element of $r_t$ occurring so that it's probability distribution can be used to evaluate the moment generating function $M(\theta) = E[e^{\theta X}]$ (where $X$ is a random variable) inside. According to this
answer, $I_p$ is given as:
$$
I_p=\max_\theta -\log(\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \text{e}^{\theta r_t})
$$
The moment generating function cannot be the same as the mean, since the mean is the first expectation $E(X)=\frac{d}{dt}M(t)|_{t=0}$. So how does one arrive at this equation without any prior guess of the underlying distribution? Are there, in fact, assumptions made or are there other steps?

I do not have deeper knowledge of the problem at hand, but: To me, this looks like assumgin IID (excess) returns and hence replacing the expectation with its estimator, i.e. the sample average.
